# React native unable to use db on APK build

Tags: react-native, sqlite, apk

I have built a dictionary app where I stored the data in a SQL DB file. When I run the app on my pc it works fine. But when I create the APK build, the db file does not work. Can you please tell me where did I make the mistake.

Comment: Which "SQL DB" are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL lite

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.